# Correct regex for FilesMatch to prevent access to all but a few files?

Tags: apache-2.2

What is the correct regex for Filesmatch to prevent access to all but a few files that the sysadmin has specified?

This is the closest I've gotten for a single file.  But unfortunately, this directive allows access to ALL the files in the same directory as `foo.php`.

```
<FilesMatch "^(?!foo\.php)$">    
      deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

For example if `bar.htm` was in the same directory as `foo.php` someone could access it from `www.mysite.com/bar.htm` if the above directive was set in `httpd.conf`

Can someone give me an example for how to prevent access to all but the following files in a single FilesMatch directive?

- foo.php
- bar.htm
- other/somestuff.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably easier to deny *everything* and then allow the files you want.

```
Order deny, allow
Deny from all
<FilesMatch (foo.php|bar.htm|other/somestuff.js)$>
  Allow from all
<FilesMatch>
```